# Default object is mutated even by using the spread operator

Tags: javascript, svelte

In svelte I want to create a form with a `Reset` button. I use for that an object in a reactive variable that is initialised with an default object `DEFAULT_OPTIONS`:

```html
<script>
    const DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {
        checked: true
    }
    
    let options = { ...DEFAULT_OPTIONS }
    
    const reset = () => {
        options = { ...DEFAULT_OPTIONS }
    }
</script>

<input type="checkbox" bind:checked={options.checked} />
<button on:click={reset}>Reset</button>
```

See the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/4dd6b4c76eb24ccb9e6a140769a7eb8f?version=3.38.2).

This one works well. However, when I try to use an nested object, then the `DEFAULT_OPTIONS` object is mutated like the `options` variable. The `reset` function doesn't work then anymore:

```html
<script>
    const DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {
        nested: {
            checked: true
        }
    }
    
    let options = { ...DEFAULT_OPTIONS }
    
    const reset = () => {
        options = { ...DEFAULT_OPTIONS }
    }
</script>

<input type="checkbox" bind:checked={options.nested.checked} />
<button on:click={reset}>Reset</button>
```

See the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/d32cc3b4f9d9433da0626e5e48490326?version=3.38.2).

Any idea why?

Comment: That's because spread syntax makes a *shallow* copy, not a *deep* (nested) copy.

Comment: @trincot Perfect thanks wasn't able to find this one in google :cry: